# Forecasting with ARIMA: still doesn't forecast into the future after appending and dyn

Tags: stata

I'm trying to forecast my dependent variable using Arima. Here's the code:

arima d.lnunits lnprice avgofitems t, ar(2,4)
predict y, dynamic(tw(2017w6))

This is supposed to give me a prediction of the future (non-existent) values of the dependent variable, but it doesn't. Instead I get:

(option xb assumed; predicted values)
(260 missing values generated)

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
C.

Answer (score 0):

The missing values suggests that data needed for the predictions are not available. Are the independent variables nonmissing for the observations at 2017w6 and beyond?

As a side point, I note the Stata weekly value. Is your time actually expressed as Stata weekly values? If so, I do not think they mean what you think they mean. Consider the following example, noting the number of days in week 52, and the day (Friday) on which weeks begin.

```
clear
set obs 366
gen float day = mdy(1,1,2016)+_n-1
gen float week = wofd(day)
format day %td
format week %tw
list in 351/l, clean

             day      week  
351.   16dec2016   2016w51  
352.   17dec2016   2016w51  
353.   18dec2016   2016w51  
354.   19dec2016   2016w51  
355.   20dec2016   2016w51  
356.   21dec2016   2016w51  
357.   22dec2016   2016w51  
358.   23dec2016   2016w52  
359.   24dec2016   2016w52  
360.   25dec2016   2016w52  
361.   26dec2016   2016w52  
362.   27dec2016   2016w52  
363.   28dec2016   2016w52  
364.   29dec2016   2016w52  
365.   30dec2016   2016w52  
366.   31dec2016   2016w52
```